# Linux Copy Specific Files

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have 1000 videos which contain both mp4 and mkv format. I want to copy all mkv files to another directory using linux commands. How could I do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your guide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd firstdir
cp *.mkv /path/to/seconddir/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sourceFile parameter, use `*.mkv`.
This tells the linux terminal to copy every file.